# Inverse factorial loop with PHP

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, factorial, inverse

I got bored and created this script for the sole purpose of just practicing looping. I'm trying to use a factorial number for example `479001600` which is the factorial of 12! and I'm feeding it to the loop to find what number is `479001600` a factorial of. Using the technique `479001600/2 -> 239500800/3 -> 79833600/4 ...-> previous_int/n+1` I've come up with the following code which works only till 12! but fails on 13! onwards:

```
<?php

    function inv($int){

        $j=2;

        for($i=0;$i<$j;$i++){

            $prod = $int/$j;

            if($prod !== 1){
                $int = $prod;
                echo $prod. "<br>";
                $j++;
            } elseif($prod == 1) {
                return $j;
            }

        }

    }

    echo inv(6227020800);  // 13!


?>
```

When I try to compute the 6227020800 to 13! I get the following output:

```
    3113510400
    1037836800
    259459200
    51891840
    8648640
    1235520
    154440
    17160
    1716
    156
    13
    1
    0.071428571428571
    0.0047619047619048
    0.00029761904761905
    1.750700280112E-5
    9.7261126672891E-7
    5.1190066669943E-8
    2.5595033334971E-9
    1.2188111111891E-10
    ...etc
```

Even though it gets to the integer 1 through the loop division, it carries on ignoring the if statement. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated, also, I want to avoid using the gmp_ functions.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Replace `$prod !== 1` (not identical) with `$prod != 1` (not equal).

Comment: "It works on my machine" :)

Comment: @SharanyaDutta Thanks. That seemed to work, why is it that a lose comparison succeeds?

Answer (score 1):

This is because 1 and 0.071428571428571 are not the same type.

Your comparison operator, `!==`, checks that the values are identical and since they are of different types, the check fails. To see for yourself try this:

```
  echo gettype(1);
  echo gettype(0.12);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that not even matter since the function should `return` and therefore end before it reaches any floats?

Comment: It shouldn't reach it, and doesn't in my testing with that code, but for some reason on his machine it does. Additionally, that comparison operator does not appear to be doing what he expects (it looks like this person is using it like "if this is not equal to that" when in fact it means "if this is not identical to that").